# Why does Bo Burnham flash on the screen at approximately 13:42 in Inside?

Tags: analysis, inside-2021

At approximately 13:42 in Bo Burnham's special *Inside*, the overlay with him as a streamer appears for a frame:

[image]

Is this an editing error, or is it intentional? If it's intentional, what might the deeper meaning behind it be?

Comment: Is this literally one frame? If so I am surprised you can see it.

Answer (score 5):

[As explained here](https://www.insider.com/bo-burnham-inside-special-details-analysis-breakdown-2021-6):

> This plays almost like a glitch and goes unexplained **until later in the special when a sketch plays out with Burnham as a Twitch streamer who is testing out a game called "INSIDE"** (in which the player has to have a Bo Burnham video game character do things like cry, play the piano, and find a flashlight in order to complete their day).
>
> By inserting that Twitch character in this earlier scene, Burnham was seemingly giving a peek into his daily routine.